# Objective C: How to highlight a tableView Cell and keep it highlighted when table is reloaded?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, highlighting

Really need some advice for this. I am trying to do a couple of things.
1) Set the first cell of the table view to be highlighted the first time the table is loaded. The user can then proceed to select/highlight other cells in the table. How can I highlight the cell for the very first time?

2) After some changes are made to the values in a row, I will reload the table data, however this will remove the highlight on the cell. Is there any way to keep the cell highlighted even after table reload.

Thanks!

Zhen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943)